# How to create this layout? Child wider than parent / padding / flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sure this is simple but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

I have two divs. A heading div max-width 500px. A main div max-width 400px. The main div should be centered horizontally in the browser window. The left hand edge of the heading div needs to align to the left hand edge of the main div. See below. The red line is the center of the browser window:

[image]

I've acheived this by adding a wrapper div with max-width 500px (the pink colour) and using extra padding on the left hand side. This works to a point. But at smaller screen sizes the extra padding on the left knocks the layout off center.

So how do I create this layout? I'm presuming I can not add the heading div as a child of the main div, because a child can't be wider than its parent. I'm guess flexbox might be the answer, but I've never used Flexbox.

This is the code I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/aqpyzogc/

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading"></div>
    <main></main>   
</div>


.wrapper {
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0 0 0 100px;
    background-color:lightpink;
    }

.heading {
    max-width:500px;
    background-color:cyan;
    height:100px;
    }


main {
    max-width:400px;
    background-color:grey;
    height:500px;
    }
```

Comment: @misorude if a child element has max-width greater than the parent element, it doesn't work. Only 'width' seems to work. And I don't want a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But at smaller screen sizes the extra padding on the left knocks the layout off center.

You can *calculate* the correct amount of padding for those viewport sizes, using the `calc()` function.

Below 600px viewport width, the remaining space is 100% minus 400px, and we need half of that for the padding-left, so:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 100px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 400px) / 2);
  }
}

.heading {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <main></main>
</div>
```

I set the body margins to 0 here as well, so that the whole thing fits with the 600px breakpoint. If you need those additional margins, you have to figure them in in the breakpoint value calculation.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqpyzogc/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. That has been a brilliant solution